# Apply function to grouped dataframe and save multiple outputs into the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          X    Z  participantNum  obsScenario  startPos  targetPos
16000 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16001 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16002 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16003 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16004 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16005 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16006 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16007 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16008 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16009 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
```

I am trying to apply a function to the 'X' and 'Z' columns that returns 3 outputs. I want to save these outputs into the dataframe. I need the function to applied to the grouped dataframe.

I've tried several ways, using something like this:

```
def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):
    a = 1.0*np.array(data)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * scp.stats.t._ppf((1+confidence)/2., n-1)
    return m, m+h, m-h

allDataF['mean_ci'] = allDataF.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])['X', 'Z'].apply(mean_confidence_interval)
```

But I get an error:
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
mean_ci = df.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])['X'].apply(mean_confidence_interval)
df.join(mean_ci.rename('mean_ci'), 
        on = ['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])
```

as `mean_ci` is a Series with indexs `['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos']`, you can not assign the values to the orgin allDataF whose index is `16000 ~ 16009`.